# Magick equivalent of GIMP Hue-Chroma transformation

Tags: imagemagick, gimp

Using Gimp, given an input image, I can improve its contrast using *Colors > Hue Chroma...* by setting *Chroma=50* (in a scale between -100 and 100) and leaving *Hue=0* and *Lightness=0*. So it appears I'm doing an HCL transformation.

Is there an equivalent command for Magick?

The following image shows the GIMP effect:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXDv3.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Not sure about this at all. I think you can get pretty close with `-modulate` if you go into an `LCH` colourspace, but I have no idea if it will work consistently. I got:

```
magick cXDv3.jpg -define modulate:colorspace=LCH -modulate 100,150 result.jpg
```

If that doesn't work, or is not to your liking, read on...

---

### Generic Method for any GIMP or Photoshop filters

The method below should allow you to replicate any GIMP or Photoshop filter with **ImageMagick** - as long as it is a pure *"point process"*, I mean one where each pixel's output value is purely derived from its input value and not an *"area process"* where surrounding pixels contribute - such as blurring or median filtering, for example.

It's called a HALD-CLUT. You would create a HALD-CLUT something like this:

```
magick hald:16 clut.png
```

Then take that file (`clut.png`) into **GIMP** and apply your GIMP processing on it and save the result as `GIMP-H0-C50-L0.png` so we know how **GIMP** affects each colour. You do that just once.

Then you go back to **ImageMagick** and apply that CLUT to your image:

```
magick input.png GIMP-H0-C50-L0.png -hald-clut result.png
```

That gives me this:

[image]

and I think you'll agree the left side looks pretty similar to the right side of your input image.

**Original Answer**

I don't know what that command does in **GIMP**, but you can convert to HCL colourspace in **ImageMagick** and select the Chroma channel for modification like this:

```
magick INPUT.PNG -colorspace HCL -channel G ...
```

You then want to do something ? to affect the Chroma channel, so try `-auto-level` for now, and then return to sRGB colourspace and save:

```
magick INPUT.PNG -colorspace HCL -channel G -auto-level +channel -colorspace sRGB RESULT.PNG
```

Then you need to provide more clues or experiment more with what that command does in GIMP - or provide examples.