# Is it possible to calculate the color curve currection applied between two images, and apply it to many others?

Tags: image-processing, colors, scikit-image

I need to keep color corrections aligned across a set of images.

Currently the workflow is:

- make some color edits to an image
- record (hopefully) the edits (this is the part that usually fails, as it entails a ton of back-and-forths in Photoshop)
- make the same edits to all other images manually

I would like instead to:

- make some edits to a small set of images
- calculate what is the color correction that has been applied
- apply same transformation to all other images

I am thinking of a workflow that is based on something similar to scikit's histogram matching, but kind of in reverse.

Is that possible at all? and if yes how?

Ideally python + scikit.image

Comment: You can use a **HALD CLUT**. You make an image with a vast number of colours, apply your processing to it and save the resulting LUT. Then you apply that LUT to your other images https://stackoverflow.com/a/76525620/2836621 and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/71996687/2836621

Comment: If you have done all the colour corrections to your image via Photoshop adjustment layers, you can just drag your adjustment layers from the corrected image and drop them onto the HALD CLUT image and save it and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a LUT, exported as a CUBE or CSP, that you authored with Photoshop using its adjustment layers:

[image: Photshop Adjustment Layers]
[image: Photoshop Export LUT]
[image: Photoshop Export LUT]

You can use [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) to read the LUT, the image, decode it and then apply the LUT.

```py
import colour

LUT = colour.read_LUT("~/Downloads/MyLUT.CUBE")

image = colour.read_image("~/Downloads/MyImage.png")
image = colour.cctf_decoding(image)
image = LUT.apply(image)

colour.plotting.plot_image(colour.cctf_encoding(image))
```

[image: Colour - LUT Applied]